# Internet is extremely slow on my computer after using firex proxy

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet

I have this mini router and on today I get slow internet speed with it on my desktop which has ubuntu. I have connected my laptop with the router and I got faster internet on the laptop. So I turned on the tethering on my phone and connected my desktop and now my internet connection is fast. However, when I connected with my router the internet is extremely slow on my desktop. I don't know what causes the problem.

I have this problem after I used a Mozilla extension named firex proxy.

Comment: There are at least two possible different problems; 1) bandwidth (try any speed test site), 2) DNS resolution that points to an unreachable server (used a VPN recently)? You can at least check #1 and update your question with the results.

Comment: @xenoid Yes, you are correct I have used the VPN recently to get into a torrent site. It was a Mozilla extension named firex proxy. How do I get my previous speed?

Comment: What I suspect  is that your DNS is pointing to the VPN; so check `/etc/resolv.conf`, normally in Ubuntu (16+ at least) your DNS is 127.0.1.1, (Ubuntu uses `dnsmasq`) if you have anything not in 127.0.x.x you can remove it.

Comment: @xenoid I have `nameserver 127.0.0.53 options edns0` in the `resolv.conf`. So do I need to remove it?

Comment: Maybe. Do you recognize that `edns0` string? Name of some interface? Is that you Ethernet or was that the tunnel? Replace by plain `nameserver 127.0.1.1` and see if it fixes/breaks things and restore if breaks.

Comment: @xenoid I have edited the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and included `nameserver 127.0.1.1`. After reboot, the `options edns0` was deleted and now I think I am getting the old internet speed.

Comment: OK, made answer from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow internet can be due to name resolution problems.  Some VPN setups change the DNS resolution to point to the VPN name servers, and it is not always correctly restored when the VPN is shut down. Afterwards your name resolution is slowed down because it tries to query a name server that has become unreachable.

You can fix this by editing `/etc/resolv.conf` and remove foreign references. In modern Ubuntu (at least since 16.04) DNS is managed by [resolvconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvconf)/[dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) and this requires your system to be its own name server (it will query other name servers under the hood). So in practice your `/etc/resolv.conf` will/should always looks like this when you are only connected to regular interfaces:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

If you find other DNS in it you can try to remove them.